# Cannot find iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, appcelerator

Just reinstalled Appcelerator Studio after a year not using it. Started a brand new project. When I run it I get:

[ERROR] Unable to find any Xcode installations that supports iOS Simulator 12.4.

However in Xcode I have plenty Simulators that run on 12.4. I can even run a new Xcode project on a Simulator.

Tried:> appc ti info

That gives me:
"
  !  Unable to find any valid iOS development provisioning profiles.
    This will prevent you from building apps for testing on iOS devices.
     You will need to log in to http://appcelerator.com/ios-dev-certs with your Apple Developer
     account, then create, download, and install a profile.
"

But I've never had to do that before.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Unable to find any valid iOS development provisioning profiles. This will prevent you from building apps for testing on iOS devices.*...But I've never had to do that before.

This is a different issue from the simulator problem. You need a developer profile in order to build your app for an iOS device. If you ever did any development on a device, rather than on a simulator, then either you did set up a profile in the past or someone did it for you. Either way, developer profiles expire after a year, so you'll need to do it again if it's been a while since you ran an app on a device.

> *Unable to find any Xcode installations that supports iOS Simulator 12.4.*

What simulators do you think you have available? Try running this command:

```
xcrun simctl list devices 12.4
```

That should list all the simulators available for iOS 12.4. If there are none, then you obviously need to create some. If there are some, then perhaps Appcelerator is looking in the wrong place. You can also do:

```
xcrun simctl list runtimes
```

to get a list of the runtimes that are installed. If those commands don't work, then you may need to:

- Make sure that you've got a version of Xcode that supports iOS 12.4 installed, i.e. Xcode 10.3 or later
- Make sure that you've installed the command line tools for that version of Xcode.
- Run `xcode-select` to select the right Xcode installation, e.g. something like: `sudo Xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` (assuming /Applications/Xcode.app is the right Xcode version)

Note that Xcode 10.3 was only released recently (as of this writing), so if you haven't installed/updated Xcode since July 22, 2019, you have an older version and need to update.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time Caleb. xcode-select did the trick!

Comment: Thank you. I had sufficient devices and runtimes installed, but it turns out a recent update to my mac required me to start Xcode again and re-install the command line tools. This was only clear once I started xcode. For some reason the xcrun commands did not complain.

Answer (score 0):

After going through this and many other comments, I found the issue was as simple as making sure the simulator was closed before I ran the build.  Please try that first before some of these more esoteric answers!